# Elliptic Integral simplification

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(roh^2 - r^2)/(r^2 - rb^2)], {r, rb, roh}, 
 Assumptions -> r > rb \[And] roh > rb \[And] roh > 1]
```

Outputs to:

```
 ConditionalExpression[(
         rb roh (-Sqrt[(1/rb)] Sqrt[-rb] EllipticE[rb^2/roh^2] + 
            I EllipticE[ArcSin[roh/rb], rb^2/roh^2]))/Abs[rb], rb + roh >= 0]
```

EDIT1:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(roh^2 - r^2)/(r^2 - rb^2)], {r, rb, roh}, 
 Assumptions -> rb > 0 && roh > rb]
Integrate[Sqrt[(m^2 - r^2)/(r^2 - m^2 + 1)], {r, Sqrt[m^2 - 1], m}, 
 Assumptions -> m > 1]
Clear["Global`*"];
Plot[-I m (EllipticE[1 - 1/m^2] - 
    EllipticE[ArcSin[m/Sqrt[-1 + m^2]], 1 - 1/m^2]), {m, 1 + 10^-6, 
  4}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Additionally to simplify using a single parameter $m>1$ defined through  $(roh = m, rb= \sqrt{m^2-1})$ one obtains plot:

[image]

Thanks for understanding/comment/intuition /about how a plot with $\sqrt{-1}$ coefficient can work, when arguments of $(K,E)$ type elliptic integrals appear to be real.

[WA plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B-I%20m%20%28EllipticE%5B1%20-%201%2Fm%5E2%5D%20-%20%20%20%20%20%20EllipticE%5BArcSin%5Bm%2FSqrt%5B-1%20%2B%20m%5E2%5D%5D%2C%201%20-%201%2Fm%5E2%5D%29%2C%20%7Bm%2C%201%20%2B%2010%5E-6%2C%20%20%20%204%7D%2C%20GridLines%20-%3E%20Automatic%5D)

Comment: Looking at result, without assumptions shows a term $\sqrt\frac{-1}{\rho}$. But then you say in the assumptions that $\rho>1$, therefore the complex number shows up.   To get rid of the complex number, then remove the assumption that causes it.

Comment: If an expression with complex components reduce to real than it must be the imaginary portions cancel.

Answer (score 3):

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(roh^2 - r^2)/(r^2 - rb^2)], {r, rb, roh}, Assumptions -> rb > 0 && roh > rb ]

(* roh (EllipticK[1 - rb^2/roh^2] - EllipticE[1 - rb^2/roh^2]) *)
```